# Arranging the values of a subset of column in R based on a common value in other column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, stringr, rbind

This simple R code creates a new column with 12 rows where 1,2 and 3 each appear 4 times respectively. The new column abc is added to the "iris1" dataset. I need to make it such that, for all the "1" in the column abc, I should get a sum of all the corresponding Sepal.Length values which have "abc" = 1. Similarly for 2 and 3.Finally I want to assign the result to a vector i.e. the vector should have 3 values in all. Please help and thanks.

```
iris1 = iris[1:12,]
a = data.frame(A1=rep(1,4))
b = data.frame(A1=rep(2,4))
c = data.frame(A1 = rep(3,4))
abc = rbind(a,b,c)
abc
iris2 = data.frame(abc,iris1)
```

Comment: I thin kyou need `iris$abc <- as.integer(iris$Species)`

Comment: Hi akrun, thanks for the help. However, I didn't get this, My issue has nothing to do with the Species Column.

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: If you run the script, "abc" column has 1,2,3 each appearing 50 times, I need to sort the Sepal.Length values corresponding to 1 in ascending order, then with 2 and then 3 without impacting the ordering of column "abc".

Comment: Ok try `library(dplyr); iris1 %>% arrange(A1, Sepal.Length)`

Comment: Hmm, I can't see Sepal.Length arranged in ascending order.

Comment: For me, it is in ascending order

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157551/discussion-between-ashmin-kaul-and-akrun).

Comment: @akrun, hi, please help me with this post, I need some help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47154749/changing-the-width-height-and-alignment-of-the-shiny-widgets-in-r?noredirect=1#comment81263002_47154749